# Create folder in www directory using PHP on UBUNTU

Tags: php, ubuntu, web, chmod

Im trying to create a folder (inside www directory) using php script. I did some configurations on UBUNTU, but still not working.

Ubuntu configuration: (user: admin - group: www-data)

```
sudo adduser admin www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www
```

PHP code:

```
function makeDir($dir)
{
$ret = @mkdir($dir, 0700);
return $ret === true || is_dir($dir);
}
```

Error: **Don't create directory.**

Reading some other posts, i found this UBUNTu configuration, but still not works:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www
sudo ls -l /var | grep www
sudo usermod -G www-data admin
sudo chmod 770 /var/www
sudo ls -l /var | grep www
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
shell_exec("md $dir");
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually depends on what user & group the httpd is running with, and if using cgi or apache mod method.  The apache's user needs access to create the directory.  My solution - usually - is to allow write access to the group.  eg running with nobody (the last line sets file access rights)

```
chown -R :nobody *
chmod -R 770 *
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 640
```

After this you can simply create directories & files from within php, but you probably need/want to change their rights so you can 'manually' access them when needed via the hosting account.